# Angular 2+ SEO for web crawlers

Tags: angular, seo, single-page-application, google-crawlers, server-rendering

I have my angular 4+ webapp which have a different header on different routes.All the components loads through angular code hence, everything is javascript and there is not much HTML except root component.Due to this, the google is not able to crawl any links.The SEO has taken a hit. I want to know whether if I add my header and footer HTML piece of code and mark it as hidden by default will google and other social sites be able to crawl my page.

I know we can use Angular  Universal and use server-side rendering, but for a temporary fix is the above solution workable? Also, apart from extra bytes of transfer from server to the client is there any downside to it?

This question is not duplicate as it refers to angular 2+ version.Most of the answers are of angularjs.

Answer (score 1):

Google is able to crawl angular websites. If you mean that given one page, it won't crawl other linked pages, the, it may be because your links to other pages are not proper anchors (`<a ...>`). You could provide a sitemap to ensure that Google can see all your pages.

Then, on each page you need to make sure you set proper title and meta

You can use angular's meta and `TitleService` (https://angular.io/guide/set-document-title) to set the title when you land on a page

```
 this.titleService.setTitle( "Page-specific title" )
```

and angular's `Meta` service (https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Meta)

```
this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: 'My page-specific description' });
```

But they best solution would still be angular universal

Comment: I have added a proper sitemap to the webmaster.btw, can you elaborate on not having proper anchor tags? Do I need to add any attributes to anchor tags?

Comment: @jalakvora are you able to crawl the site?

Answer (score 0):

Two things. First of all, doesn't matter that you don't have HTML, Google bot is capable of parsing your website anyway (they problem is that other bots might not).

If you use Angular properly without manipulation DOM in weird way (weird = jQuery or similar), you don't use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` and you used only Angular methods you should find any problem running you app as an Angular Universal.

Try Angular Universal first before going and using any hack as implementing the SSR capabilities in Angular is easy (https://angular.io/guide/universal)

Good luck with that!

Comment: when I search on google, it is not able to index any of my landing pages routes.I have added proper meta tags.what could be the cause of it? Also, what are things need to be done when you say "If you use Angular properly".I know  Angular SSR is easy to setup but we just needed a temporary fix.